# Snakemake tabular configuration, expand, and merge - how to expand input files correctly?

Tags: snakemake

I would greatly appreciate a little pointer for the following.   I have a TSV samples table:

```
Sample  Unit    Tumor_or_Normal Fastq1  Fastq2
A       1       T       reads/a.t.1.fastq       reads/a.t.2.fastq
A       2       N       reads/a.n.1.fastq       reads/a.n.2.fastq
B       1       T       reads/b.t1.1.fastq      reads/b.t1.2.fastq
...
```

and is read in

```
samples = pd.read_table(config["samples"], dtype=str).set_index(["Sample", "Unit", "Tumor_or_Normal"], drop=False)
samples.index = samples.index.set_levels([i.astype(str) for i in samples.index.levels])
```

I would like to merge all bam files that have the same Sample and Tumor_or_Normal.  For example, C-1-T.bam and C-2-T.bam and C-3-T.bam should be merged into C-T.bam.   I have a rule

```
rule merge_recal_by_unit:
    input:
        expand("recal/{{Sample}}-{Unit}-{{Tumor_or_Normal}}.bam",
                Unit=samples.loc[samples.Sample].Unit)
    output:
        bam=protected("merged/{Sample}-{Tumor_or_Normal}.bam")
    params:
        ""
    threads:
        8
    wrapper:
        "0.39.0/bio/samtools/merge"
```

but this gave an InputFunctionException.   I've also tried replacing the expand with

```
lamblda wildcards: expand("recal/{{Sample}}-{Unit}-{{Tumor_or_Normal}}.bam",
                           Unit=samples.loc[wildcards.Sample].Unit)
```

but this gave me a syntax error, and

```
expand("recal/{{Sample}}-{Unit}-{{Tumor_or_Normal}}.bam",
       Unit=samples.index.get_level_values('Unit').unique().values())
```

resulted in the message that numpy.ndarray object is not callable.  This seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400171/how-to-use-list-in-snakemake-tabular-configuration-for-describing-of-sequencing/54405965#54405965) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786201/snakemake-group-files-together-by-wildcard) question, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.   Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to query the samples table to get all the rows sharing the same `Sample` and `Tumor_or_Normal` and use the list of `Unit` to construct the input list of bam files. If so, something like this should do:

```
rule merge_recal_by_unit:
    input:
        lambda wc: ['recal/{Sample}-%s-{Tumor_or_Normal}.bam' % x for x in 
            samples[(samples.Sample == wc.Sample) & (samples.Tumor_or_Normal == wc.Tumor_or_Normal)].Unit]
    output:
        bam=protected("merged/{Sample}-{Tumor_or_Normal}.bam")
    ...
```